# iOS 15 crash CoreTelephony

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine, core-telephony

Some of my iOS users can't enter my app (they receive a black screen or crash).

I noticed a huge spike in the crashes section, only for ios 15 users
I can't see it on my iPhone device and can't find any information about my specific logs.

[image]

```
Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note: EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread: 0


Kernel Triage:
VM - pmap_enter failed with resource shortage
VM - pmap_enter failed with resource shortage
VM - pmap_enter failed with resource shortage
VM - pmap_enter failed with resource shortage
VM - pmap_enter failed with resource shortage


Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x00000001b7815204 __ulock_wait + 8
1 libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000180b9a344 _dlock_wait + 56 (lock.c:326)
2 libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000180b9a274 _dispatch_once_wait + 120 (lock.c:382)
3 Foundation 0x00000001827d78f0 -[NSCoder _walkAllowedClassListLookingForClass:forKey:allowedClasses:strictModeEnabled:alwaysEnforceExplicitSubclasses:] + 1068 (once.h:84)
4 Foundation 0x00000001826f6abc -[NSXPCDecoder _validateAllowedClass:forKey:allowingInvocations:] + 188 (NSXPCCoder.m:744)
5 Foundation 0x0000000182908f28 _decodeObject + 1364 (NSXPCCoder.m:1018)
6 Foundation 0x00000001826eeb54 _decodeObjectAfterSettingWhitelistForKey + 164 (NSXPCCoder.m:1057)
7 Foundation 0x000000018274b728 -[NSXPCDecoder decodeObjectOfClasses:forKey:] + 52 (NSXPCCoder.m:1118)
8 CoreTelephony 0x000000018159d520 -[CTServiceDescriptorContainer initWithCoder:] + 236 (CTServiceDescriptor.mm:180)
9 Foundation 0x0000000182908f6c _decodeObject + 1432 (NSXPCCoder.m:1026)
10 Foundation 0x00000001826e166c -[NSXPCDecoder _decodeObjectOfClasses:atObject:] + 76 (NSXPCCoder.m:1098)
11 Foundation 0x00000001826e5e5c _NSXPCSerializationDecodeTypedObjCValuesFromArray + 936 (NSXPCCoder_InvocationSerialization.m:396)
12 Foundation 0x000000018271d0cc _NSXPCSerializationDecodeInvocationArgumentArray + 500 (NSXPCCoder_InvocationSerialization.m:523)
13 Foundation 0x00000001826d6514 -[NSXPCDecoder __decodeXPCObject:allowingSimpleMessageSend:eek:utInvocation:eek:utArguments:eek:utArgumentsMaxCount:eek:utMethodSignature:eek:utSelector:isReply:replySelector:interface:] + 788 (NSXPCCoder.m:1236)
14 Foundation 0x000000018278db40 -[NSXPCDecoder _decodeReplyFromXPCObject:forSelector:interface:] + 84 (NSXPCCoder.m:1130)
15 Foundation 0x000000018270e6ac -[NSXPCConnection _decodeAndInvokeReplyBlockWithEvent:sequence:replyInfo:] + 176 (NSXPCConnection.m:259)
16 Foundation 0x00000001826e94b4 __88-[NSXPCConnection _sendInvocation:eek:rArguments:count:methodSignature:selector:withProxy:]_block_invoke_3 + 212 (NSXPCConnection.m:1630)
17 Foundation 0x00000001826fda60 -[NSXPCConnection _sendInvocation:eek:rArguments:count:methodSignature:selector:withProxy:] + 2632 (NSXPCConnection.m:1651)
18 CoreFoundation 0x0000000180ebc204 ___forwarding___ + 1088 (NSForwarding.m:3618)
19 CoreFoundation 0x0000000180ebb5c0 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 96
20 CoreTelephony 0x00000001815857e0 -[CoreTelephonyClient getDescriptorsForDomain:error:] + 336 (CoreTelephonyClient.mm:165)
21 CoreTelephony 0x00000001815852ec -[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo descriptors] + 72 (CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.mm:596)
22 CoreTelephony 0x00000001815844c4 -[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo initWithClient:] + 484 (CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.mm:292)
23 CoreTelephony 0x000000018158af40 -[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo init] + 112 (CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.mm:256)
24 UnityFramework 0x00000001038fad50 -[ADCDevice init] + 108 (ADCDevice.m:205)
25 UnityFramework 0x00000001038fa378 __25+[ADCDevice sharedDevice]_block_invoke + 24 (ADCDevice.m:92)
26 libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000180b99950 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:560)
27 libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000180b9b1d8 _dispatch_once_callout + 32 (once.c:52)
28 UnityFramework 0x00000001038fa35c _dispatch_once + 16 (once.h:84)
29 UnityFramework 0x00000001038fa35c +[ADCDevice sharedDevice] + 112 (ADCDevice.m:91)
30 UnityFramework 0x00000001039a3430 0x103798000 + 2143280
31 UnityFramework 0x00000001039a2260 0x103798000 + 2138720
32 UnityFramework 0x00000001039a2100 0x103798000 + 2138368
33 UnityFramework 0x00000001039ccaa0 +[GADMediationAdapterAdColony load] + 32 (GADMediationAdapterAdColony.m:43)
34 libobjc.A.dylib 0x000000019943b6c4 load_images + 1088 (objc-loadmethod.mm:204)
35 dyld 0x00000001004d5ee4 dyld4::RuntimeState::notifyObjCInit(dyld4::Loader const*) + 164 (DyldRuntimeState.cpp:1558)
36 dyld 0x00000001004da3b8 dyld4::Loader::runInitializersBottomUp(dyld4::RuntimeState&, dyld3::Array<dyld4::Loader const*>&) const + 196 (Loader.cpp:1301)
37 dyld 0x00000001004e0570 dyld4::Loader::runInitializersBottomUpPlusUpwardLinks(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const + 124 (Loader.cpp:1314)
38 dyld 0x00000001004d9b54 dyld4::APIs::dlopen_from(char const*, int, void*) + 512 (DyldAPIs.cpp:1435)
39 CoreFoundation 0x0000000180fc909c _CFBundleDlfcnLoadFramework + 140 (CFBundle_Binary.c:610)
40 CoreFoundation 0x0000000180f56058 _CFBundleLoadExecutableAndReturnError + 412 (CFBundle.c:1445)
41 Foundation 0x0000000182737978 -[NSBundle loadAndReturnError:] + 428 (NSBundle.m:588)
```

Comment: may be related to https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/693623

Answer (score 0):

I believe this error message is somehow related to [GADMediationAdapterAdColony](https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/ios/mediation/adcolony), I would suggest updating your ads plugin to the latest available version.

Comment: Thank you, but I have the most updated one

Comment: I just checked and I received the same error- without GADMediationAdapterAdColony.  (I checked a crash from before installing that, and the crash logs are similar to my post (just without the GADMediationAdapterAdColony line.  I still don't understand what is this crash but it only happens with ios15+